# ASP.NET Custom ConfigurationSection from referenced project not working?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've created a custom class that inherits from `System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection`, implemented like this (this is obviously just to get the real configuration running):

```
public class Config : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("quoteOfTheDay", DefaultValue = "It is what it is.", IsRequired = false)]
    public string QuoteOfTheDay
    {
        get
        {
            return this["quoteOfTheDay"] as string;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("yourAge", IsRequired = true)]
    public int YourAge
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)this["yourAge"];
        }
    }
}
```

The full namespace + name of the class is MyApp.Core.Config, it's located in the MyApp.Core project which compiles to the MyApp.Core.dll assembly. I've then referenced this project from my ASP.NET/MVC3 project, which is called MyApp.UI. I've edited the `Web.config` file to add the `sectionGroup` and `section` elements like this:

```
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="myAppConfigGroup">
      <section name="myAppSection" 
           type="MyApp.Core.Config, MyApp.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKey=null" 
           allowLocation="true" 
           allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <myAppConfigGroup>
    <myAppSection>

    </myAppSection>
  </myAppConfigGroup>
```

However, it doesn't seem like the type `MyApp.Core.Config` get used to validate the configuration or provide intelli-sense as I edit the configuration. Here's some observations I've made:

- I defined the `yourAge` property as `IsRequired = true` and the application runs fine without it.
- I can even change the type (to some type that doesn't even exist like Foo.Bar) in the `<section>` element, and everything still runs fine
- But if I remove the `<section>` element, the app doesn't run.

I'm baffled, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably not using the configuration?
If you are not using it, it will only do a check if the root nodes are registered via `configSections` but it will not look at the details at that point.

When you will actually load it using `ConfigurationManager.GetSection` the settings will be validated and in your case of this configuration it will trigger an exception telling that the required `YourAge` property is missing.